# Custom taxonomy page returns 404

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, 404-error

I've created a custom post type and a custom taxonomy. I can create new posts and assign those taxonomies, but it returns a 404 when I go to `mydomain.com/mycustomtaxonomy/termslug`.

Here is my code:

```
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Videos', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Video', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Nuevo', 'portfolio item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Nuevo video'),
    'edit_item' => __('Editar video'),
    'new_item' => __('Nuevo video'),
    'view_item' => __('Ver videos'),
    'search_items' => __('Buscar videos'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'rewrite' => array("slug" => "video"),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes')
); 

register_post_type( 'videos' , $args );
flush_rewrite_rules();

// Register custom taxonomy

register_taxonomy("familia_videos", array("videos"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Categorias de Videos", "singular_label" => "Categoria de videos", 'rewrite' => true  ));
```

And my permalink structure:

```
/%postname%/
```

I've created: taxonomy-familia_videos.php

I've refreshed the permalinks structure, but I always get a 404.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> but it returns a 404 when I go to mydomain.com/mycustomtaxonomy

The problem is that you're expecting behavior that simply doesn't exist.  Just like mysite.com/category will 404, so will mysite.com/mycustomtaxonomy